# How to retrieve the data from table that are indirectly connected in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

How can I get the room data from booking through roomAvailabilities table??

I tried using :

```
    $booking = Booking::all();
    $booking-> RoomAvailability;   //it works
    $booking -> Room;              //doesnot work
```

In booking model:

```
public function room()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Room', 'App\RoomAvailability');
}
```

**Sql Server query that might be similar to what I want:**

SELECT * FROM dbo.Booking as b

INNER JOIN dbo.RoomAvailability as ra on b.bookingId = ra.BookingId

INNER JOIN dbo.Room as r on r.roomId = ra.roomId

**Below is the sample of my table structure.**

**Booking:**

```
id 
check_in_date
check_out_date
number_of_rooms
```

**RoomAvailabilities:**

```
id 
booking_id
room_id
status
```

**Room:**

```
id
room_number
```

**Booking Model**

```
public function roomAvailability()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RoomAvailability::class);
}
```

**RoomAvailability Model**

```
public function booking()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Booking::class);
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many did you try doing this

Comment: Thank You for helping out @Aless55 :) ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a ManyToMany (belongsToMany) relationship, as @Aless55 said. Thus, it is expected that a booking can contain one or more rooms, while a room can be in (none or) more than one booking.

When defining the function by calling the belongsToMany method (and the inverse in the other table), you can access the other model. Your case would look something like this:

**Booking Model**

```
public function rooms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Room::class, 'RoomAvailabilities');
}
```

**Room Model**

```
public function bookings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Booking::class, 'RoomAvailabilities');
}
```

Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order to fetch the pivot table. Note that in your case, the second parameter (optional) needs to be used because the nomenclature of this table (RoomAvailabilities) was outside the expected standard of Eloquent.

There is a convenient way to access the link table attributes. Just access the generated attribute called pivot. Example:

```
$booking = Booking::find(1);

foreach ($booking->rooms as $room) {
    echo $room->pivot->status;
}
```

To get several bookings with related rooms, use the `with` method ([eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)), like this:

```
$bookings = Booking::with('rooms')->get();
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). There you will find other possibilities such as:

- Customizing The pivot Attribute Name
- Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns
- Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models